# coordinates of the highest intense point of an image detected by webcam

Tags: c, windows, blob, webcam, tracking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function to return coordinates of the maximum intensity point of the image grabbed from a webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550215/function-to-return-coordinates-of-the-maximum-intensity-point-of-the-image-grabb)

I want to get the coordinates of the highest intense point in an image being taken by webcam.
I am using opencv.Image is being captured by using cvCapFromCAM().
I am using windows 7 and i am programming in C programming language.

I dont know how compiler deals "intensity" of a blob..
All i want to do is to track a LED of red color which has greater intensity than any other thing present in the image.
And in return i want to get the x and y coordinates of the led detected..

Answer (score 1):

Well you will either be getting a value between 0 and 255 as an integer or 0.0f and 1.0f as a float/double representing each part of an RGB mix of colours (probably).  You just need to look at each pixel and figure out which one has the value for the R componenet closest to 255 / 1.0f.

Comment: Can you please post code

Comment: @Revs No sorry, this explination is more than enough to be able to do it.  If you can not figure out how to do it from this explination then you need to go look at some resources and learn to program first.  All you need to do is create a loop going through each pixel and determining if its red value is higher than any previously seen red value.